# Cross-thread operation not valid for invalidating graphics object

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to create graphics that will redraw every 500ms using a Timer, but I keep running into a cross-thread operation.  Can somebody please tell me why this is happening?

Error:

```
Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'GraphicsBox' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
```

I'm using WinForms, and have a PictureBox called "GraphicsBox" in the main form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace NamespaceName
{
    public partial class FormName : Form
    {
        Graphics g;

        public FormName()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer();
            t.Interval = 500;
            t.Enabled = true;
            t.Elapsed += (s, e) => this.GraphicsBox.Invalidate(true);
        }

        private void FormName_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.GraphicsBox.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(OnPaint);
        }

        protected void OnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            g = e.Graphics;
            //Draw things
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can fire the `OnPaint` event I have from the timer's 'tick' (or 'elapsed')?  I believe that will do the trick.  All I'm trying to do is redraw the graphics object, and I will change things in the code to cause it to be drawn differently.

Comment: Why don't you just use a system.windows.forms.timer? That will use the right thread automatically...

Comment: @MarcGravell Sigh, I knew it had to be something simple...  thank you!

Comment: This code is actually valid, calling Invalidate() from a threadpool thread is okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem here is that there are at least 3 classes named `Timer` and probably more (in different namespaces, but with different behaviours). You are using one that calls back on a worker thread, and UI controls don't like that due to thread affinity.

If you switch to `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` it will invoke the callback on the UI thread (presumably via sync-context, but I guess it might be implemented using the message loop directly). This is then not a cross-thread operation, and will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling the `GraphicsBox` object on the wrong thread, `System.Timers.Timer.Elapsed` is called on a different (Background) thread.

You can either -

**a)** Switch to using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, which will run on the same thread as `GraphicsBox`

or

**b)** Quick and nasty -

```
t.Elapsed += (s, e) => this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate(){ this.GraphicsBox.Invalidate(true); }));
```